# How to get current url or input parameters in web.py template

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I have a web page designed with web.py. I use `web.template.render()` and an HTML template file to draw a table in this web page.

I pass a list of items to this template, and would like to show the data in different pages using GET method and `offset` and `count` parameters (i.e. `http://mywebsite/records?offset=10&count=15`).

I am looking for a way to get the input values of `offset` and `count` and also the current url in the **HTML template file**, so I would be able to put links to next page and previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates get data either passed into them (e.g., `render.home(a, b, c)`) or as a global (explicitly passed in as a dict via `globals` parameter when you define your renderer).

Your example is easier to do by getting the information in python, and passing it into the template. This allows you to error check the values, provide defaults, etc.

So, have your GET() extract the proper information and pass it to the template:

```
class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        my_render.index(url=web.ctx.fullpath,
                        offset=web.input().offset, 
                        count=web.input().count())

==== index.html ====
$def with(url, offset, count)
<table>
   <tr><td>URL is: $url</td>
       <td>OFFSET is: $offset</td>
       <td>COUNT is: $count</td></tr>
</table>
```